# Typedef error after including header file multiple times

Tags: c, embedded, microchip, atmel, mplab

I am writing c code targeting a SAME51 based Atmel/ Microchip processor.   I am using Microchip's MPLABX to compile and run the code.

I have header files that are included multiple times in multiple .c files.  I am running into an error when I include my `triac.h` into `keypad.c`:

```
In file included from ../src/keypad.c:23:0:
../src/triac.h:39:54: error: expected ')' before 'uintptr_t'
 typedef void (*p_triac_isr_reg)(TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK, uintptr_t);
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~
../src/triac.h:78:5: error: unknown type name 'p_triac_isr_reg'
     p_triac_isr_reg isr_register;
```

triac.h:

```c
#ifndef TRIAC_H
#define TRIAC_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "./config/Test/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.h"
#include "./config/Test/peripheral/tc/plib_tc_common.h"  // << Needed to add this

typedef void (*p_triac_funct)();
typedef void (*p_triac_isr_reg)(TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK, uintptr_t);

typedef struct triac_t
{
    bool is_enabled;
    uint16_t current_setting;
    uint16_t min_period;
    uint16_t max_period;
    p_triac_funct isr;
    p_triac_isr_reg isr_register;
    bool (*set_output)(uint16_t);
    uint16_t (*get_output)();
} triac_t;

extern triac_t *p_ac_triac;      
extern frequency_t lineFrequency;   // Line Frequency (FREQ_50HZ or FREQ_60HZ)

#endif // TRIAC_H
```

I have included `triac.h` in `triac.c`, `keypad.c`, and a couple other files.  If I remove the `#include "triac.h"` from `keypad.c` everything compiles fine without any errors.  I am pretty stuck at this point.

### Update

I needed to add `#include "./config/Test/peripheral/tc/plib_tc_common.h"` to my `triac.h` thanks @tstanisl!  I thought it was included in `"./config/Test/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.h"` but I was mistaken.  I apologize for not giving all pieces necessary, but the code relies on working with the MPLAB Harmony Framework.

**plib_tc_common.h**

```c
typedef void (*TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK) (TC_COMPARE_STATUS status, uintptr_t context);
```

I was thrown off by this error since the same header file was included in multiple other `.c` files without any errors.  The other `.c` files did not have any `#includes` that defined `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK` so I am still unsure on **WHY** it worked before.

Comment: It looks that definition of TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK is missing. Missing header?

Comment: Are you closing the `#ifndef TRIAC_H`?

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but remember that in C an empty argument list in a function declaration means the function can take an indeterminate number of arguments of indeterminate type. So if `p_triac_funct` doesn't take any arguments you should say it explicitly with a `void` argument specifier.

Comment: It seems `uintptr_t` is not known. Did you include `stdint.h`?

Comment: @tstanisl I was trying to sanitize the post, but the TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK is included by a `#include` that is present in the file, but not in this post.


@zois, I updated the post, because I forgot to include it, but in the file it is closed


@Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the information, I'll explicitly state it with the `void` argument


@Gerhardh I included `stdint.h` in the file, just not the post, I updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: @jtilles Any code posted should be able to replicate the problem by itself.

Comment: The thing about empty argument lists in C mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude also applies to `uint16_t (*get_output)();` in `struct triac_t`.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve] to show us. Unrelated problems only distract from the actual problem you're asking about.

Comment: We can't compile this because we don't have the header you reference.  Anyone should be able to copy and paste your code and get the same error you do when compiled.

Comment: So where is `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK` defined? Is it defined by the `#include "./config/Test/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.h"` newly added to the posted code? Please add that information to the question text. Also, please show the actual definition of `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK` if possible. There is probably something wrong with the way it has been defined.

Comment: @tstanisl You were correct!  It was a missing header file defining TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK.  I guess every other .C file I included `triac.h` in also included the header file `./config/Test/peripheral/tc/plib_tc_common.h`

Comment: You should have left the question as it was and then posted an answer to your own question (or just deleted the question if it has no benefit as a community resource).  Do not edit the question to include the solution. Now as a question, it makes no sense because the you have corrected the code, it no longer exhibits the error.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the error reason has been identified in comments, only this lack of clarity remains:

> I was thrown off by this error since the same header file was included in multiple other `.c` files without any errors.  The other `.c` files did not have any `#includes` that defined `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK` so I am still unsure on **WHY** it worked before.

The reason for this surely is that *before* you hadn't included `<stdint.h>` prior to the

```
typedef void (*p_triac_isr_reg)(TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK, uintptr_t);
```

(as in your original question before you *updated the post*); this way, `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK` and `uintptr_t` were just arbitrary parameter names (without types) in an old-style, still legal function parameter list.

Comment: You are wrong here. `A parameter type list specifies the types of, and may declare identifiers for, the
parameters of the function.`. So a declaration like `int foo(int, double);` is valid.

Comment: It's not about `int foo(int, double)`, it's about `void (*p_triac_isr_reg)(TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK, uintptr_t)`, and you missed that _`.c` files did not have any `#includes` that defined `TC_COMPARE_CALLBACK`_, hence this was **not** a type.